# How to compare 2 huge CSV files, based on column names specified at run time and ignoring few columns?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, optimization, compare

I need to write a program that compares 2 CSV files and reports the differences in an excel file. It compares the records based on a Primary key (and sometimes a few Secondary keys) ignoring a list of other columns specified. All these parameters are read from an excel.
I have written a code that does this and works okay for small files but the performance is very poor for huge files (some files that are to be compared have way more than 200K rows).

The current logic uses csv.DictReader to read the files. I iterate over the rows of first file reading row by row, each time finding the corresponding record in the second file (comparing Primary and Secondary keys). If the record is found, I then compare all the columns ignoring those specified in the excel. If there is a difference in any of the columns, I write both records in the excel report highlighting the difference.
Below is the code I have so far. It would be very kind if someone could provide any tips to optimize this program or suggest a different approach.

```
primary_key = wb['Parameters'].cell(6,2).value              #Read Primary Key

secondary_keys = []                                         #Read Secondary Keys into a list
col = 4
while wb['Parameters'].cell(6,col).value:
    secondary_keys.append(wb['Parameters'].cell(6,col).value)
    col += 1
len_secondary_keys = len(secondary_keys)

ignore_col = []                                             #Read Columns to be ignored into a list
row = 8
while wb['Parameters'].cell(row,2).value:
    ignore_col.append(wb['Parameters'].cell(row,2).value)
    row += 1

with open (filename1) as csv_file_1, open (filename2) as csv_file_2:
    file1_reader = csv.DictReader(filename1, delimiter='~')
    for row_file1 in file1_reader:
        record_found = False
        file2_reader = csv.DictReader(filename2, delimiter='~')
        for row_file2 in file2_reader:
            if row_file2[primary_key] == row_file1[primary_key]:
                for key in secondary_keys:
                    if row_file2[key] != row_file1[key]:
                        break
                compare(row_file1, row_file2)
                record_found = True
                break
        if not record_found:
            report_not_found(sheet_name1, row_file1, row_no_file1)

def compare(row_file1, row_file2):
    global row_diff
    data_difference = False
    for key in row_file1:
        if key not in ignore_col:
            if (row_file1[key] != row_file2[key]):
                data_difference = True
                break
    if data_difference:
        c = 1
        for key in row_file1:
            wb_report['DW_Diff'].cell(row = row_diff, column = c).value = row_file1[key]
            wb_report['DW_Diff'].cell(row = row_diff+1, column = c).value = row_file2[key]
            if (row_file1[key] != row_file2[key]):
                wb_report['DW_Diff'].cell(row = row_diff+1, column = c).fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid',
                                        fill_type='solid', 
                                        fgColor=Color('FFFF0000'))
            c += 1
        row_diff += 2
```

Comment: Try using ```pandas``` library by creating dataframes

Answer (score 0):

You are running into speed issues because of the structure of your comparison.  You are using a nested loop comparing each entry in one collection to every entry in another, which is O(N^2) slow.

One way you could modify your code slightly is to redo the way you ingest the data and instead of using `csv.DictReader` to make a list of dictionaries for each file, would be to create a single dictionary of each file manually using the the primary & secondary keys as dictionary keys.  This way you could compare entries between the two dictionaries very easily, and with constant time.

This construct **assumes** that you have unique primary/secondary keys in each file, which it seems like you are assuming from above.

Here is a toy example.  In this I'm just using an integer and animal type as a tuple for the (primary key, secondary key) key

```
In [7]: file1_dict = {(1, 'dog'): [45, 22, 66], (3, 'bird'): [55, 20, 1], (15, '
   ...: cat'): [6, 8, 90]}                                                      

In [8]: file2_dict = {(1, 'dog'): [45, 22, 66], (3, 'bird'): [4, 20, 1]}        

In [9]: file1_dict                                                              
Out[9]: {(1, 'dog'): [45, 22, 66], (3, 'bird'): [55, 20, 1], (15, 'cat'): [6, 8, 90]}

In [10]: file2_dict                                                             
Out[10]: {(1, 'dog'): [45, 22, 66], (3, 'bird'): [4, 20, 1]}

In [11]: for k in file1_dict: 
    ...:     if k in file2_dict: 
    ...:         if file1_dict[k] == file2_dict[k]: 
    ...:             print('matched %s' % str(k)) 
    ...:         else: 
    ...:             print('different %s' % str(k)) 
    ...:     else: 
    ...:         print('no corresponding key for %s' % str(k)) 
    ...:                                                                        
matched (1, 'dog')
different (3, 'bird')
no corresponding key for (15, 'cat')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the Pandas library as suggested by @Vaibhav Jadhav using the below steps:
1. Import the 2 CSV files into dataframes. 
e.g.:

```
try:
    data1 = pd.read_csv(codecs.open(filename1, 'rb', 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore'), sep = delimiter1, dtype='str', error_bad_lines=False)
    print (data1[keys[0]])
except:
    data1 = pd.read_csv(codecs.open(filename1, 'rb', 'utf-16', errors = 'ignore'), sep = delimiter1, dtype='str', error_bad_lines=False)
```

2. Delete the columns not to be compared from both the dataframes.

`for col in data1.columns: 
    if col in ignore_col: 
        del data1[col]
        del data2[col]`

3. Merge the 2 dataframes with `indicator=True`

`merged = pd.merge(data1, data2, how='outer', indicator=True)`

4. From the merged dataframe, delete the rows that were available in both dataframes.

`merged = merged[merged._merge != 'both']`

5. Sort the dataframe with the key(s)

`merged.sort_values(by = keys, inplace = True, kind = 'quicksort')`

6. Iterate the rows of the dataframe, compare keys of the first 2 rows. If the keys are different row1 exists only in one of the 2 CSV files. If keys are same iterate over individual columns and compare to find which column value is different.

Answer (score -1):

It is a good use case for Apache Beam.

Features like "groupbykey" will make matching by keys more efficient.

Using an appropriate runner you can efficiently scale to much larger datasets.

Possibly there is no Excel IO, but you could output to a csv, database etc.

```
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/groupbykey/
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/
```